# Nextjs SSG 10 milion records

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have next js app & I have an API that returns 10 million posts,
I want to know that is it standard that I using the SSG method to do that?
plus I may add posts at any time.

Comment: Currently, if implement properly, your build will take a long time. I believe they are adding a new NextJs feature where it will generate the blog page when a user first tries to open it and then caches it for future requests.

Comment: @SILENT
I implement it and it did take a long time to build,
But, is it cache this build for the future builds?
and if it is, if I change something in these posts, how this will be handled?

Comment: @Mohammad it is writted in the official doc, the cache is erase for each new build

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continuing from the comments,

Most likely with your current implementation, you probably have the following disadvantages:

1. It takes more time to build the app
2. To add new content or update existing, we need to rebuild the app

However, there are new options being developed to overcome some of the disadvantages

Incremental Static Generation - Fallback Mode - It can generate a set of pages at the build time but it can also generate new pages on-demand as needed.

Incremental Static REgeneration - Next.js can rebuild these pages on-demand as it gets requests. But unlike SSR, they do not generate on every page request. You can set a timeout called unstable_revalidate in seconds.

You can find out more at - https://arunoda.me/blog/what-is-nextjs-issg